# What is the meaning of `new int*[rowCount];` when allocating memory to a 2D array? Is a 2D array an array of pointers to array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

https://stackoverflow.com/a/936702/462608

> A dynamic 2D array is basically an array of pointers to arrays.

[How do I declare a 2d array in C++ using new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new?rq=1#comment62942586_936702)

> Oh my God, this is complete garbage, this is utterly wrong. This is no 2D array. "A dynamic 2D array is basically an array of pointers to arrays." – NOOOO, FFS! T (*ptr)[M] = new T[N][M]; is the correct solution… No amount of arrays-of-pointers will ever be the same as an array-of-arrays

`new int*[rowCount];`.

- **What does star indicate there?**
- Is a 2D array an array of pointers to array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The star is part of the type of what is being allocated. `new int*[rowCount];` allocates a dynamic array of `rowCount` pointers-to-`int`, and returns a pointer to the first one.
2. No. A 2D array is an array, whose elements are 1D arrays, i.e. `T[M][N]`, as opposed to an array of pointers, whose elements are... well, pointers.
   The difference is easy to spot: a 2D array is backed by a single, contiguous chunk of memory, while an array of pointer (that themseves point to arrays) has its memory scattered around in no particular order.

Answer (score 4):

In this expression

```
new int*[rowCount];.
```

there is allocated an array with `rowCount` elements of type `int *`. That is each element of the array is a scalar object.

A multidimensional (or two-dimensional) array is an array elements of which are in turn arrays.

Thus to allocate a two-dimensional array you should write

```
new int[rowCount][colCount];
```

Or you could write

```
typedef int TElement[colCount];

new TElement[rowCount]; .
```

The problem with this allocation is that the variable `colCount` must be a compile-time constant. If the value of the variable is not known at compile-time you may not use such an allocation.

So in this case usually an array of pointers is allocated as it is shown in your question

```
int **a = new int*[rowCount];.
```

and then each element of the one-dimensional array is initialized by the address of a newly allocated one dimensional array like

```
for ( size_t i = 0; i < rowCount; i++ )
{
    a[i] = new int[colCount];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What does star indicate there?

The syntax here is `new type [size]`. In `new int*[rowCount]`, `int*` is the type, i.e. int pointer.

> Is a 2D array an array of pointers to arrays?

It's different in dynamic and static multidimensional arrays. In static arrays, memory is allocated as 1D array (linear) and accessed as a 2D array.

A 2D dynamic array is an array of pointers to `type`, which, in your case, is `int`. Each element points to the first element of `type`, if initialized. In simpler words, it is an array of addresses to first elements of `type`. While accessing, it just adds `sizeof(type)` to that address to access the required index.

Comment: The first half of this answer is perfectly correct, but the second half is downright wrong.

Comment: Hey thanks for that. Edited it to prevent misleading anyone.

Comment: I edited to prevent misleading and wrote nothing else because I thought Quentin's answer would be enough. But here you go!